# Metadata version mismatch for module while creation a browser build

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic3

I am working on ionic 3 application and getting below error with "**ionic cordova build browser --prod**" command -

> Error: Metadata version mismatch for module
>               C:/Users/con-backend/Desktop/dev_newRepo/con-dashboard/node_modules/ionic-tooltips/dist/tooltip-box.component.d.ts,
>               found version 4, expected 3 Error: Metadata version mismatch for module
>   C:/Users/consectus-backend/Desktop/devHUB_newRepository/consectus-dashboard/node_modules/ionic-tooltips/dist/tooltip-box.component.d.ts,
>   found version 4, expected 3
>       at StaticSymbolResolver.getModuleMetadata (C:\Users\consectus-backend\Desktop\devHUB_newRepository\consectus-dashboard\node_modules@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:24474:34)
>       at StaticSymbolResolver._createSymbolsOf (C:\Users\consectus-backend\Desktop\devHUB_newRepository\consectus-dashboard\node_modules@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:24260:46)
>       at StaticSymbolResolver.getSymbolsOf (C:\Users\consectus-backend\Desktop\devHUB_newRepository\consectus-dashboard\node_modules@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:24241:14)
>       at C:\Users\consectus-backend\Desktop\devHUB_newRepository\consectus-dashboard\node_modules@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:23023:30
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at extractProgramSymbols (C:\Users\consectus-backend\Desktop\devHUB_newRepository\consectus-dashboard\node_modules@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:23022:79)

here is my package.json:-

```
{
    "name": "ConDashboard",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "author": "Ionic Framework",
    "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
        "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
        "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
        "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
        "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "4.1.3",
        "@angular/common": "4.1.3",
        "@angular/compiler": "4.1.3",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.1.3",
        "@angular/core": "4.1.3",
        "@angular/forms": "4.1.3",
        "@angular/http": "4.1.3",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "4.1.3",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.1.3",
        "@angular/router": "^7.0.4",
        "@ionic-native/core": "^3.12.1",
        "@ionic-native/deeplinks": "^4.20.0",
        "@ionic-native/network": "^3.0.0",
        "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "3.12.1",
        "@ionic-native/status-bar": "3.12.1",
        "@ionic/storage": "2.0.1",
        "@reactivex/rxjs": "^5.5.3",
        "@types/papaparse": "^4.5.2",
        "chart.js": "^2.7.2",
        "cordova-browser": "5.0.4",
        "cordova-plugin-console": "^1.1.0",
        "cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview": "^2.4.0",
        "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^4.1.0",
        "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
        "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
        "crypto-js": "^3.1.9-1",
        "ionic-angular": "^3.6.0",
        "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "^2.2.1",
        "ionic-tooltips": "^3.0.0",
        "ionicons": "3.0.0",
        "moment": "^2.24.0",
        "moment-duration-format": "^2.2.2",
        "papaparse": "^4.6.0",
        "rxjs": "^5.5.12",
        "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
        "zone.js": "0.8.12"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@ionic/app-scripts": "2.1.4",
        "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
        "typescript": "2.3.4"
    },
    "description": "An Ionic project",
    "cordova": {
        "plugins": {
            "cordova-plugin-console": {},
            "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
            "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
            "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
            "ionic-plugin-keyboard": {},
            "cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview": {}
        },
        "platforms": [
            "browser"
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made changes in node modules/@angular/compiler.bundles/complire.umd
because had problems while creating a prod build  (ionic cordova build browser --prod) , so i added false condition to the below if condition.And this fixed the issue.

```js
if (moduleMetadata['version'] != SUPPORTED_SCHEMA_VERSION && false) {
                var /** @type {?} */ errorMessage = moduleMetadata['version'] == 2 ?
                    "Unsupported metadata version " + moduleMetadata['version'] + " for module " + module + ". This module should be compiled with a newer version of ngc" :
                    "Metadata version mismatch for module " + module + ", found version " + moduleMetadata['version'] + ", expected " + SUPPORTED_SCHEMA_VERSION;
                this.reportError(new Error(errorMessage));
            }
```